# TabViewItem error Property Content does not support values of type MainPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have created a `TabView` and for each icon I am trying to insert as content the pages I created previously. I can't insert them inside the `TabViewItem`, `visualStudio` reports me as an error.

My pages are inside the '`Pagine`' folder in `Visual Studio`

[image: screen]

```
<xct:TabViewItem
      TabWidth="{Binding TabWidth}"
      Text="Home"
      FontFamily="MyIcon"
      ControlTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}">
             <xct:TabViewItem.Icon>
                 <FontImageSource  Color="Gray" FontFamily="MyIcon" Glyph="{x:Static dayr:FontIconClass.Home}"/>
             </xct:TabViewItem.Icon>
             <xct:TabViewItem.IconSelected>
                 <FontImageSource  Color="Black" FontFamily="MyIcon" Glyph="{x:Static dayr:FontIconClass.Home}"/>
             </xct:TabViewItem.IconSelected>
    
              //ERROR
              <Myapp:MainPage></Myapp:MainPage>      
     </xct:TabViewItem>
```

UPDATE:
The error is:

> Property 'Content' does not support values of type 'MainPage'

Comment: it is really unclear what exactly you are doing with this exception occurs?  Are you doing something with the solution explorer?  Or just typing in text in the editor?  Or something else?  Have you looked at the log file?

Comment: It doesn't make me insert the namespace I created inside the TabViewItem. The namespace is not recognized

Comment: Agree with Jason the question is totally unclear and have only very few details, please reformulate the issue and include relevant details/code/erros.

Comment: VS is actually showing an error message when you do this?  That's odd, and **again** I would suggest you look at the log file.  Otherwise I would verify that the namespace you are using matches the namespace used in the page's .cs

Comment: I have updated the code and the error generated by Visual Studio. as soon as I enter the namespace I cannot find the various pages I have within the project

Comment: Please post the relevant error message in your **original post**.  It is a waste of our time when we try to help you and you do not include that very important information

Answer (score 0):

The `Content` property of `TabViewItem` does only supports objects of type `View`. While you are providing `MainPage` which is not of type `View`.

[Source from Docs: TabViewItem  properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview)

| Property | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Content | View | The content of the tab. Anything can be used as content. |

Comment: Is there any way to navigate my page?

Comment: Only `TabbedPage` supports to navigate between pages.  Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page .

Comment: (https://ibb.co/Nx8yGXg) does tabbedpage have graphics like this?

Comment: You need to customize the tab item in custom renderer .